# Plotly funnel chart: What if one number is vastly out of proportion with all the rest?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly funnel chart with the following values:
194482896
2041923
822553
530146
13372

Because the top number is so factors larger than the rest I get a funnel chart where you can't see the lower numbers:

[image: Out of proportion funnel chart]

When you remove the first value, you get a nice chart like so:

[image]

Is there a way to manipulate the chart so it more evenly shows all numbers?  Here is the code:

```
 fig = go.Figure(
        go.Funnel(
            y=[
                #                "Impressions",
                "Clicks",
                "Learners Reached",
                "Learners Acquired",
                "Game Completed",
            ],
            x=[clicks, LR, LA, gc_count],
            textposition="inside",
            textinfo="value+percent initial",
            #           opacity=0.65,
            marker={
                "color": ["deepskyblue", "lightsalmon", "tan", "teal"],
                "line": {
                    "width": [4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1],
                    "color": ["wheat", "wheat", "blue", "wheat", "wheat"],
                },
            },
            connector={"line": {"color": "royalblue", "dash": "dot", "width": 3}},
        )
    )
```

Comment: By setting the text position setting to automatic, if the width is too narrow to display the text, it will automatically be displayed on the outside. `textposition='auto'` [Updated graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbQdb.png)